# SQL how to select date with limit?

Tags: sql

I have a limited history table. It uses composite keys - one of the columns is the timestamp in `long`.

I want to select/delete rows that are the oldest, and keep the latest 1000 by checking the timestamp. How do I write the statement for such a case?

Comment: Something like `DELETE FROM table WHERE column < xxx` . You will have to determine what xxx should be based on the values you have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fire delete query escaping 1000 records.

Not in a query will be scape 1000 latest records and rest will be deleted.

```
Delete from table where Id not in(select top 1000 Id from table order by date desc )
```